# I want to join tables and combine similar informations that they have

Tags: t-sql, join, common-table-expression

I have two tables, I want to join the two tables and combine the values from table 2 that the table1 has. Just like this:

```
  Table1
------------
Column1 | Column2
------------
James|  5 
Bond |  3


  Table2
------------
Column1 | Column2
------------
James|  0
Bond |  0
Dive |  0
```

and I want to have an output Like this:

```
  Output
------------
Column1 | Column2
------------
James|  5
Bond |  3
Dive |  0
```

I tried union, union all , left join, right join, full join. I also researched about CTE but I don't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION ALL` will suffice your needs. The result of subquery is the aggregated in `Column2` for every `Column1`.

```
SELECT  Column1, SUM(Column2) Column2
FROM
        (
            SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Table2
        ) x
GROUP   BY Column1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0648a/10)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦═════════╗
║ COLUMN1 ║ COLUMN2 ║
╠═════════╬═════════╣
║ Bond    ║       3 ║
║ Dive    ║       0 ║
║ James   ║       5 ║
╚═════════╩═════════╝
```